# jQuery Validate .valid() function doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

If I do this:

```
$('#form').validate({
    // ....
})
```

And then I hide the form `#form`:

```
$('#form').hide() .
```

Then I check `$('#form').valid()`, I always get `true` even if the form should be invalid.

Example: Click `checkTestValid` with nothing in the text field when the form is showing (it alerts `false`), then use `clickHide` to hide the form, and then use `checkTestValid` to check again (it alerts `true`):

```js
$('#testForm').validate({
  rules: {
    testInput: {
      required: true,
    }
  },
});

$(".btnTest").click(function() {
  $("#tab2").hide();
})
$(".btnTest2").click(function() {
  $("#tab2").show();
})
$(".clickTestVelid").click(function() {
  alert($("#testForm").valid())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

<div id="tab1">
  <button class="btnTest">clickHide</button>
  <button class="btnTest2">clickShow</button>
</div>
<div id="tab2">
  <form id="testForm">
    <input required value="" name="testInput">
  </form>
</div>

<button class="clickTestVelid">clickTestValid</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, it ignores hidden elements since the default value of [`ignore` option](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore) is [`":hidden"`](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) so update the [`ignore` option](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore).

```
$('#testForm').validate({
  // updated to ignore class selector to ignore only elements with class .ignore
  ignore: ".ignore"
  rules: {
    testInput: {
      required: true,
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: I figured it had to be something like that. :-)